# Await is only valid.. NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm getting the error await is only valid in async function. I find this weird as I took the code of the docs itself.

Why would this throw the error?

```
const OpTrade = require('trade-opskins-api')
const OPSKINS_API_KEY = 'key';

const opTrade = new OpTrade(OPSKINS_API_KEY);
const interface = 'user'; // item | trade | user
const method = 'GetProfile';

// const response = await opTrade.userGetProfile() 
// or
const response = await opTrade[interface + method]()

console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
```

Comment: Which docs? Have a look at some async/await tutorials. The setup is an `async` function, and you can `await` method calls inside that.

Comment: You can only use the `await` keyword inside of a function declared with `async`

Comment: you can only use `await` in an `async` function. Top level `await`s is not yet supported

Comment: @ExplosionPills would there be any way for me to convert the current code into a working one, this is the package used; https://www.npmjs.com/package/trade-opskins-api

Thus the code they provided.

Comment: Simply wrap all your code in `(async () => { /* your code here */ })()`

Comment: @ExplosionPills not only response?